# geting null, but expected randon UUID

Tags: java

geting null, but expected randon UUID
entity

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

  private UUID userId;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private Gender gender;
  private Integer age;
  private String email;

   public enum Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE
    }
}
```

service method

```
public int insertUser(User user) {
        return repository.insertUser(UUID.randomUUID(), user);
    }
```

repository method

```
@Override
public int insertUser(UUID userId, User user) {
    database.put(userId, user);
    return 1;
}
```

controller

```
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<Integer> insertNewUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    int result = service.insertUser(user);
    if (result == 1) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
}
```

after insert entity and getting, it has userId null
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You forgot to show your `getAll` method

Comment: What is `database` in `database.put(userId, user)`. At what point is `userId` applied to the `user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@Override
public int insertUser(UUID userId, User user) {
    user.setUserId(userId);
    database.put(userId, user);
    return 1;
}
```